# "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1" error, while working with fetch / array

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was looking for about an hour for a solution of my issue.
I found several similar questions, but no one helped me. And I also realised, that a lot of people gets this error message.
Because I'm really frustrated with my issue, i will ask you to help me.

I'm trying to select some stuff out of my database and store it inside an array. After that, I want to fill my table with the array and show it inside my modal.

But I got an error every time I tried to story my select inside an array.

The affected line (row 275) is the line, with this code: while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($user))

This is what my code looks like right now:

**My Modal (geheim.php)**

```
<div id="modal-timeline" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Timeline</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <?php
      include '../db.php';
      $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM timeline");
      $user = $statement->fetch();
      ?>
      <div>
        <td>Login Page Database</td>
     <table border="1">
        <th>Benutzer</th>
        <th>Tätigkeit</th>
        <th>Zeitstempel</th>
        </tr>

    <?php

         while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($user))
         {
             ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['benutzer']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['taetigkeit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['zeitstempel']; ?></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Abbrechen</a>
      <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue bestaetigen" type="button" name="bestaetigen">Bestätigen
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
  </form>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**The included connection (db.php)**

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=einteilungsplan', 'root', '');
?>
```

**My Database (mysql)**

[image: Database]

And of course, my error message looks like this:

**Error Message**

[image: Error message]

Thanks a lot for every help

Comment: @Chris Already checked the "possible dublicate before". Correct my if I'm wrong. But the issue with the "possible dublicate" is, that his query was false. I dont think that I have the same issue...

Comment: You mixing the `PDO` and `mysqli`. Please once refer the difference between both of them.

Comment: @DD77 Thanks a lot. I didn't knew the difference between PDO and mysqli... I always thought it's same and you can use it together. I'm trying to fix it with the new knowledge right now ;)

Comment: @CallMeLeonardo You are right, your issue was no exactly the same. However, the underlying problem remains the same: a bad request or a query not yet executed returns False. For that reason, I will maintain the dup link for other readers. In any case, happy to see that you finally solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code may be it will work for you.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM timeline");
$statement->execute();
$result_data = $statement->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

...

foreach( $result_data as $row ) {
 ...  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Your code worked nearly perfect. Just a small error. It's foreach instead of for.

Comment: oops sorry! it was typo mistake.